# null(A) = $(row(A))^{\perp}$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

Let U = span{$v_1$,$v_2$,…,$v_k$}, $v_i \in R^n$, and let A be the k x n matrix with the $v_i$ as rows.

Show that null(A) = $(row(A))^{\perp}$ I have prove that 
$U^{\perp}$ = { $x \in R^n :  Ax^{T} = 0 $} So shouldn't this prove it already or is there more steps to it ?

Comment: If you show that $U^\bot = \ker A$ then you are finished.

Comment: is that by definition of $U^{\perp}$?

Comment: Well, not exactly, the definition is $U^\bot = \{ x | \langle x,u \rangle = 0, \forall u \in U \}$. Since $U = { \cal R} A$ here, it amounts to the same thing.

Comment: I see that makes sense thank you !